# Issues Opening Spyder via Anaconda

Tags: python, spyder

I was forced into some software updates on my laptop (ThinkPad) and after the update when I tried to open Spyder (via Anaconda) and it won't open. I don't have any experience in errors like this or fixing this stuff (and I am aware this may be something that is super simple). Please help. This is the application launch error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3651, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3526, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 871, in setup
self.help = Help(self, css_path=css_path)
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\help\plugin.py", line 68, in __init__
color_scheme = self.get_color_scheme()
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugins.py", line 347, in get_color_scheme
return super(BasePluginWidget, self)._get_color_scheme()
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\base.py", line 446, in _get_color_scheme
return get_color_scheme(CONF.get('appearance', 'selected'))
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\gui.py", line 114, in get_color_scheme
color_scheme[key] = CONF.get("appearance", "%s/%s" % (name, key))
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\manager.py", line 228, in get
return config.get(section=section, option=option, default=default)
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 976, in get
return config.get(section=section, option=option, default=default)
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py", line 513, in get
raise cp.NoOptionError(option, section)
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'custom-1/background' in section: 'appearance'
```

Thanks,

Rachel

Comment: Please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there `spyder --reset`. Then start Spyder again. That should fix your problem.

Comment: where in the Anaconda prompt is that. I found the restart option but its only for the whole program, I can't find how to reset an application with in Anaconda

Comment: You need to type that command and then hit `Enter` to run it.

Comment: CARLOS YOU SAVED MY LIFE

Comment: I'm glad that trick worked! Happy Spydering!

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Carlos!!!!! Sypder forced me to update and  now won't open again but its a different error this time!! Can you help me????

Comment: What's error? If you already opened a question here about it, please post the link below and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095040/issues-opening-spyder-after-conda-updating thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run spyder on the terminal?
It should be prebuild in Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spyder config file should contain but is missing 'custom-1/background' in section: 'appearance'.  If you have no experience, the easiest thing for you to do is uninstall and install Spyder (via Anaconda).  Your other option is to find the config file called in line 513 of C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\config\user.py".  Then open the config file (if it exists) and correct it. If the file is not found, search for that config file and place it in the expected location.

Comment: So I tried the uninstall/re-install and now luck. How would I correct the config file? @cadvena