# Issues Opening Spyder after Conda updating

Tags: python, spyder

I've been coding in Jupyter primarily due to a professors preference so when I opened Sypder to use recently it wanted me to update it up and I did via Conda and now it is giving me this when I try to open it. I tried to force Sypder back to the previous version but no luck. Can someone help??

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 210, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 119, in 
from spyder.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 19, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.collectionseditor import (
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\collectionseditor.py", line 57, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.collectionsdelegate import (
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\collectionsdelegate.py", line 31, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.objectexplorer.attribute_model \
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\objectexplorer\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from .objectexplorer import ObjectExplorer
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\objectexplorer\objectexplorer.py", line 33, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.widgets.codeeditor import CodeEditor
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\widgets\codeeditor.py", line 70, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.panels import (ClassFunctionDropdown,
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\__init__.py", line 13, in 
from .codefolding import FoldingPanel
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\codefolding.py", line 32, in 
from spyder.plugins.editor.panels.utils import (
File "C:\Users\cyrra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\editor\panels\utils.py", line 15, in 
import textdistance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textdistance'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can rollback a conda env; e.g. `conda list --revisions` then select the revision number you want to go back to and use `conda install –revision revision_number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error was caused by an incorrectly packaged version of Spyder but it's fixed now.

To get the fix, please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

```
conda update spyder
```

If that doesn't work, please run

```
conda remove --force spyder
conda install spyder=4.2.1
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: CARLOS SAVES THE DAY FOR THE SECOND TIME!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem. Glad Spyder is working for you again.